# Default value of a BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

I have a code in which I am converting from `Long` to `BigInteger` and vice-versa. While converting from `Long` to `BigInteger`, I want to make sure that there is no `NullPointerException`. So the code looks like this:

```
(myModel.getLongVariable()!=null)?BigInteger.valueOf(myModel.getLongVariable()):**??**;
```

If you see the **??** part, I am not sure what default value to put there. The [BigInteger specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) don't provide a default constructor like `new BigInteger()`.

What everyone here suggests is the most obvious option i.e. using `BigInteger.ZERO`. But zero is one of the values and would go accordingly in rest of the flow. I would basically write it in an xml and I am exploring if I can rather make it as blank instead of zero

Any further suggestion appreciated.

Comment: If it's actually `long`, it can't be `null`. Object references can be `null` but `long` is a primitive so it initializes to zero by default.

Comment: Depends on what you want to return. But you have some constants like `BigInteger.ZERO`.

Comment: A long is typically initialized to `0`. Make your `BingInteger` take a `0` value?

Comment: All I apologize for the mistake. Its the wrapper class Long

Comment: If you're going to use this default value for multiplication or division operation, you will prefer to use `BigInteger.ONE` instead of `BigInteger.ZERO`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : What everyone here suggests is the most obvious option. But zero is one of the values and would go accordingly in rest of the flow. I would basically write it in an xml and I am exploring if I can rather make it as blank instead of zero.

Comment: But from your current explanation readers may think zero must be the default value, I'm just stating that this is not always true. If you're going to do, for example, financial operations, and need the default value for one of the factors in a big formula, the default value should be 1 instead of 0. If would be better if you specify this in question (and in answers as well).

Answer (score 3):

There are two sensible value to return for a `null` parameter:

- zero (`BigInteger` provides the constant [`BigInteger.ZERO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#ZERO) you could use for that)
- `null`

A null is the closest thing to the "blank" you would like to return:

```
return myModel.getLongVariable() != null
    ? BigInteger.valueOf(myModel.getLongVariable())
    : null;
```

Comment: @Bohemian, my suspect it is the OP himself. Not sure though :)

Comment: going with null seems to the option for now, trusting the null checks in my application. Will keep the question open though for any more suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `myModel.getLongVariable()` is returning a `Long` object: you can use `BigInteger.ZERO` as default value:

```
myModel.getLongVariable()!=null)? BigInteger.valueOf(myModel.getLongVariable())
                                : BigInteger.ZERO;
```

Other constant fields of the [**`BigInteger`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/class-use/BigInteger.html) class are:

1. **`BigInteger.ONE`**: The BigInteger constant one
2. **`BigInteger.TEN`**: The BigInteger constant ten.

There is another constant, which is not mentioned inside the documentation for not letting anyone to know:

**`BigInteger.TWO`** : has value of `2`, which is `private`

**Edit:**

> The BigInteger specifications don't provide a default constructor like
>   new BigInteger().

`BigInteger` is a public class. Who is stopping you to extend and implement this constructor ?

```
public class CBigInteger extends BigInteger {


    public CBigInteger()
    {
        super("-12345678944546"); // testing with a default value
    }
}

BigInteger cBig = new CBigInteger();
System.out.println(cBig.toString()); // prints "-12345678944546"
```

Comment: I can read them in the java docs. Thanks for pasting here though. But, zero is one of the values and would go accordingly in rest of the flow in my application. I would basically write it in an xml and I am exploring if I can rather make it as blank instead of zero

Comment: I have mentioned a constant which you won't know by reading the documentation :P. I have seen you have edited your question after reading the answer here. I don't know who has downvoted, but your edition with out a mark probably misleading the downvoter. Thank you

Comment: Again, ZERO, ONE and TWO all leads to proper values which I want to avoid.

Comment: @G.V, you can't use `TWO` as it is private object. I have updated the answer. Have a look

Comment: doesn't make a difference. super("-12345678944546")... still needs a default numerical value. What I want is a blank.

Comment: yes, I was just trying to make a point. To demonstrate a way. You can do anything to assign a default value you want. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion:  You give it a default value.

```
 BigInteger mydefault = BigInteger.ZERO;
```

Comment: Use `BigInteger.ZERO` instead.